# Virtual host for magento2 under lampp service for Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, apache, ubuntu

I  tried to set virtual host for Magento2(2.2.5) Project in Ubuntu system under **Lampp service**.

I added this piece of code under **opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
  <VirtualHost *.:80>
  ServerName magento2.local
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento2/"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento2/">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

And added that under **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1     magento2.local
```

Uncommented below piece of line under **nano /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf**

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Restarted the service

```
/opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

After this when I try to hit **magento2.local** it again redirects with the normal URL **localhost/Magento2**

Nothing works.

Welcome for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you change in db? core_config_data table and after that flush cache and check

Comment: Hi @Kul thanks for the reply.Should I change in core_config_data.Then if I want to keep two virtual hosts for the same project how it will be possible.For example "example1.loc","example2.loc" I want these two domains for the same project.Then in DB how can I mention the two.

Comment: you can only specify 1 url in core_config_data table so not possible to use same db for 2 different url

Comment: Hi @Kul Then whats the use of virtual host.I'm planning to have two domains for the same project so that it will be useful when I switch the language.

Comment: Okay @anil if you want different domain for language then create store view/store/website and make virtual host that will works for you